# Navigation Bar Background Image too big

Tags: ios, xcode, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I am trying to change the background image for my navigation bar using `setBackgroundImage: forBarMetrics:` in my setting method.

Problem is the image doesn't fit onto the bar, looks like the image is stretched at least double the original size...

The image size is **320 x 44**...

I tried rename image to @2x, but it didn't change a thing...

I tried assign this image to `navigationItem.titleView` but the view got cut off on the edge...

**does any one have hint how to set the image so that it won't get stretched?**

```
UINavigationBar *naviBar = [self.navigationController navigationBar];
UIImage *img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"NavBar02@2x.png"];
[naviBar setBackgroundImage:img forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: codes added, please take a look thanks!

Comment: NO!!! Don't rename the image to "@2x". Never do that, you will always use the non-retina version of the image for UI elements. The "@2x" is for iOS to automatically use instead of low resolution imagery if the device has a retina screen.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

ok i got it finally!

problem: navigation bar takes images thats 320 x 44 pixels, since each point in iPhone is 2 pixels, if you are using points for navigation bar, the image that you use will look like its stretched 4 times (2x for y, and 2x for x coordinate).

to solve it, simply add file extension @2x to your image file (e.g. yourImgName@2x.png). You must rename it BEFORE you drag into Xcode! it will NOT work if you try to rename it in Xcode.

ps. DO NOT include @2x in your code, just the file name like so
[UIImage imageNamed: @"yourImgName.png"]

hope this helps

Comment: Only retina iPhone takes 2 pixels for each point. That's why you need to prepare two sets of assets.

Comment: Thanks a lot for sharing. My problem was that I was renaming the @2x inside xCode. And iOS wouldn't set the scale of my image to 2. Thanks

Comment: So what does everyone think about just providing a retina display version and allowing it to be scaled down for non retina? I've tried this and the retina image looks fine in non retina phone.

Comment: What happens if you create this image with [UIImage imageWithData:data] and thus there never is any filename for the image? How do you specify the normal image vs the @2x image?

Answer (score 1):

You should have two image. One is 320x44 pixles and name as NavBar02.png. Another is 640x88 pixels and name as NavBar02@2x.png.

iOS will select the suitable image based on device's resolution.

Answer (score 0):

for all icons, apple recommends the following. [image: image sizes for navigation and tab bars.]

To resize, open your image in Preview. go to

> tools -> adjust size.

Hope that helps.